# Magento2 , how to remove decimal values from layered navigation

Tags: magento2, price, frontend, layered-navigation

I'm trying to find out if there is any way to remove decimals from layered navigation. We don't have product prices with decimals but Magento show 0-99.99,100-199.99 etc. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Your goal could be achieved in the next way:

app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface"
                type="YourNamespace\YourModule\Model\PriceCurrency" />
</config>
```

app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/Model/PriceCurrency.php

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

class PriceCurrency extends \Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency implements PriceCurrencyInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    const PRECISION_ZERO = 0;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function format(
        $amount,
        $includeContainer = true,
        $precision = self::PRECISION_ZERO,
        $scope = null,
        $currency = null
    ) {
        return $this->getCurrency($scope, $currency)
            ->formatPrecision($amount, $precision, [], $includeContainer);
    }
}
```

The rewritten method is used not only for layered navigation. Please test if nothing is broken on frontend before releasing it on live server.

Comment: Thanks, im trying to look for something which only works for layered navigation. I found this extension  https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal but its removing decimals from all places. Checking the possibility of customizing it.

Answer (score 1):

One extension is there with the help of it, you can achieve the rounding.

It will surely help you in some ways.

https://github.com/karliuka/m2.Price

This module deals with the price rounding management in Magento 2.

Answer (score -1):

you can use round() php function. eg

```
$price = 129.56
echo round($price);
```

it will display 130.

Comment: Where should i use this function, which file and location, please?